# State where within the book a reference was cited

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I am using a `plain` sort in my thesis. However, ordering the authors by last name does not help the reader find where the author/reference was cited within the book.

Using the `unsrt` option would not help me for 2 reasons:
1. it will give a relative location of the citation based on the previous/later citations but not the page number (for example, reference 10 is cited after 9 in the book, and before reference 11)
2. a reference can be cited throughout multiple pages in the book (for example, reference 10 can be cited at page 20, 50, 100).

Is there a way to automatically sort my references alphabetically, and at the end of each reference have the page numbers where the reference was cited within the book?

Answer (score 6):

There is a package `backref` for use with BibTeX, which also works with Hyperref.
With `Hyperref` it should suffice to add a package option `backref` or `backref=page`.

It is not compatible with BibLaTeX, which has an option `backref=true, false`.