# Hyperref, Natbib: Curious backref behaviour

Tags: hyperref, back-referencing

I have prepared the following MWE from the answer I found at [formatting-back-references-in-bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography). If the option `backref=page` is forwarded to `hyperref` with `\hypersetup` then the back references do not appear. But passing this option while calling the package works. Why is this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  backref=page
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01,B02}.

\clearpage

Some more text \citep{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note from the `hyperref` manual:

> Some options can be given at any time, but many are restricted: before `\begin{document}`, only in `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`, before first use, etc.

`hyperref` disables the `backref` option when the package is loaded. The reason for this restriction with `backref` is simply to make the implementation easier. (Note that it is supported to put the `\hypersetup{backref}` in `hyperref.cfg`.)

Note the warning you get when attempting to set the `backref` option after it has been disabled:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `backref' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 10.
```

This is the standard warning text for disabled `hyperref` options, and is perhaps a bit misleading. It should say that the option has to be specified sooner.

Comment: I should have looked at the warning. I am using silent package. On another note, referencing to your answer for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54541/precise-back-reference-target-with-hyperref-and-backref , has the patch been tested with `natbib`? Are there any known issues?

Comment: @devendra: I have just updated my answer there for `natbib` support. Only time will tell what issues remain...

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem for me, i.e., by using `\usepackage[backref = page]{hyperref}` instead of passing the option to the `\hypersetup{...}`, even if it is the first thing that follows. An alternative is to explicitly load `\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}`.