# Create links from references in bibliography to usages in text

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, links

With the hyperref package I now automatically get links from citations in text to the full citation in the bibliography.

Is there a way to automatically get the reverse as well? How can I generate links from a bibliography to usages in text? You can find an example of this in the bibliography for Wikipedia articles.

Comment: the `backref` option is what you're looking for.  for more than you probably want to know about it, see [Precise back-reference target with hyperref and backref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54541/579).

Comment: shall we say that your question is a duplicate then?

Comment: Naw, the linked question asks about specifics of backref while this question is asking if there is a way to do what backref does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `backref` option to `hyperref` will reference the number of the page on which
a citation appeared.  there are many questions here that ask about back references,
but i couldn't find one that exactly answers this question in a straightforward
manner.

the question [Precise back-reference target with `hyperref` and `backref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54541/579) expounds on exactly where the link arrow
points when such a link is taken (the top of the cited page, not to the exact location
of the citation), with copious details.