# Create hyperlink between citation call-out and printed entry?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

I want to create cite source in latex using texmaker and mendeley. In particular, whenever I click on the cited reference it directly goes to reference part where that cited reference is mentioned.

Comment: `\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}`? (See [Create links from references in bibliography to usages in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215414))

Comment: I suggest to read [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) which will enhance your understanding and massively improve the quality of your question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention *how* you create your citation call-outs, so I will assume that you're using either BibTeX or biblatex to manage the bibliographic entries, the citation commands, and the formatting of the bibliography itself. If that's the case, all you need to do is add the instruction

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

to your preamble. Note that this instruction should (in general) occur after all other packages have been loaded.