# cross reference?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I can reference a figure (or table) from text using `\label(fig:example)` between `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`, and using `\ref(fig:example)` within my text.

However, my figures are at the end of my document (a long document), and after I look at any of the figures, I would like to go back to the text where I left for the figure.  Is there any command that can link me back to the text from the figure so that I don't have to scroll back up to look for the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! :D You can use the `[backref=page]` option, like `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}`, however it links back to the page, not the exact point. For that, see this question: [Precise back-reference target with hyperref and backref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67852/4778)

Comment: Just use the “Go back” feature in your PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question:

1. Insert `\hypertarget{A}{text}` in your text. `{A}` is the label and `{text}` is the sentence where you want to come back from your table (I have applied it to my tables).
2. Put `\hyperlink{A}{(Go back to text)}` between `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`, right above `\end{table}`.
3. Highlighted (Go back to text) is placed beneath the table. Click it to go back to the sentence.