# Two questions about bibtex and hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I spent around six hours figuring out how latex works for my literracy review; and I was wondering two things :

I used hyper ref to go from a citation to the bibliography; but I would like to know how I can return back to my citation with ease . (I used \printbibliography and can't figure how to print it elseway)

I would like to set an image in my headers and footers which when you click on it it redirects you to a specific section, and I can't figure on internet how it would be possible.

If any of you knows how I could do, please help me.

Comment: use the `Alt + left arrow`.

Comment: I'd rely on the built-in capabilities of your pdf browser to set up a method for returning from a formatted bibliographic entry to the citation call-out.

Comment: `biblatex` has an option called `backref`, which places references to each page in your document where a source was cited in the bibliography entry. It is not really like a "go back" feature, but it comes close-ish. For the real "go-back experience", like Ulrike and Mico, I would recommend the relevant feature of your PDF viewer.

Comment: You could also try something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396713/35864

Comment: Please note that questions on this site should always revolve around *one* specific issue. If you want to ask about two issues, please ask two separate questions. That makes your question easier to answer in one go and makes it more relevant for future readers of the site.